# What are some good practices while creating AngularJS directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**What are some good practices that can be followed while creating angularjs directives?**

consider:

- size of the link function
- what to do/what not to do in link function
- use of scope.$apply

Comment: Without knowing more, it's hard to say exactly: 1. Can you move some of your directive code into service(s)? 2. Can you improve your code commenting to assist with debugging? 3. Can you improve your variable names to assist with debugging? 4. Can you reduce / eliminate any of the `scope.$apply` calls you have? The answer to these (and other improvements) are almost certainly *yes*, but without seeing your code, we can't give any specific feedback for your use case.  Best practices run far and deep!

Comment: Question is far too broad. If you want to resolve problems with digest cycles, ask specific question that shows problem code

Comment: why do you have so large link functions ? Are you handling too much html in your directive ? Can you split your directive in more smaller reusable components ?

Comment: *"what are good practices"* is still far too broad a question. There are various style guides that you can read that will perhaps help

Comment: i hope i am clear now with this edit.. Dennis Nerush gave an answer that was somewhat useful but i need to know more since i am already following those guidlines @charlietfl

Comment: Probably better to take some real code and put it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . read their guidelines first

Comment: Well, enough of it. Thanks for being so generous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you read the angular style guide.
You'll find all the best practices regarding all the different angular components.

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#directives

Comment: that gives some basic directions. but yes was helpful